WP Bakery Accordian Active Text Color
I'm trying to generate css to change the color of my text for the active content header in my accordion for WP Bakery. I used the following for the background and it worked, but now I need the text to be white
.vc_tta.vc_general .vc_tta-panel.vc_active .vc_tta-panel-title { 
  background-color:  #8B68AC ! important;
}

I tried this:
.vc_tta.vc_general .vc_tta-panel.vc_active .vc_tta-panel-title { 
  background-color:  #8B68AC ! important; 
}

The background worked but I need the text color to be white

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

What's the difference between the two code snippets you posted?

You can set color property to white in your code. In this case, it will make sure your text color to white it's because color property will be applied for all text under the class.
.vc_tta.vc_general .vc_tta-panel.vc_active .vc_tta-panel-title { 
  background-color: #8B68AC !important; 
  color: white !important;
}

